# Enter a valid time format in java

Tags: java

I am currently working as a software tester. I have a scenario to test a time format.

I want to enter a valid time format using java program. I tired but couldn't get a good answer.

I want to enter the time(hh:mm:ss) in correct format. It accepts the time as specified by the format HH:MM:SS.  time should be separated by colons and excpet colons no other characters like /,-  should be  print invalid .
And hour range from 0 to 23, minute range from 0 to 59 and second should be range from 0 to 59.

And only numbers are acceted, if I enter character it will print invalid time format.

And these 2 values  20:62:00 and 20:80:00,  also invalid because minute should range from 0 to 59.

This is I tried :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlarmTime {
public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of test case");
    int a = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the HH");
    int h = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the MM");
    int m = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the SS");
    int ss = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Time is" + h + ":" + m + ":" + ss);

    if (h >= 0 && h <= 23 && m >= 0 && m <= 59 && ss >= 0 && ss <= 59) {
        System.out.println("Valid test case" + h + ":" + m + ":" + ss);
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid test case");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of test case
4
Enter the HH
22
Enter the MM
33
Enter the SS
44
Time is22:33:44
Valid test case22:33:44

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here I wrote the test cases as 4 and then again how to write the next test case 2.  and also I need to write a test case for invalid input like enter characters .

Comment: I have a question. Why do you not use some testing suite to automate your job? Like Junit or something.

Comment: You are testing with `||` (which is or), you wanted `&&` (which is and). `if(0<=h<=23 && 0<=m<=59 && 0<=ss<=59){`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(0<=h<=23 ||0<=m<=59||0<=ss<=59)
```

is not a valid syntax. You cannot chain `<=` operator.

You should compare one to one each operand and use `&&` operator between the comparisons.

This

```
if(0<=h<=23)
```

should be :

```
if(0<=h && h<=23)
```

**Anyway, it is not a straight and reliable way to do the task**.
Use  rather a  `DateTimeFormatter` and instead `int`, use a `String` variable that will contain the input with the correct formatting :

```
StringBuilder dateInput = new StringBuilder();
System.out.println("Enter the number of test case");
int a = dateInput.append(s.next());

System.out.println("Enter the HH");
dateInput.append(s.next()).append(":");

System.out.println("Enter the MM");
dateInput.append(s.next()).append(":");

System.out.println("Enter the SS");
dateInput.append(s.next());

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

try{
   LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(dateInput.toString(), formatter);
   System.out.println("Valid");
 }
 catch(DateTimeParseException e){
     System.out.println("Invalid");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers are pointing out clearly, you got your conditions wrong. It is simply wrong to go `if (hour <= 0)` to then print "valid".

But beyond those simple syntactic problems: you are **re-inventing** the wheel here. Unless this is some kind of exercise where you were asked to write such code yourself, you use the power of the Java date/time APIs:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String str = "13:42:10";
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

The `parse()` call will throw an exception when the incoming string can't be parsed. See its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-). You also want to study the available [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here, It has to be an `and` condition and not an `or`.
Hour has to be below 24 and minutes have to be below 60 and seconds have to be below 60.

```
if(0<=h<=23 && 0<=m<=59 && 0<=ss<=59){
    System.out.println("Valid test case"+h+":"+m+":"+ss);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("invalid test case");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just accept `hh:mm:ss` instead of putting it as 3 variables, and then validate it by trying to parse it to a Date.

Here is how:

```
System.out.println("Enter date as HH:MM:SS");
String a = s.nextString();
try { 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("12-12-2017 "+yourString);          
    // Parsing success, means a valid test case.
    System.out.println("Valid test case : "+a);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Parsing failed, so the case is invalid!
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` and set its `lenient` property to `false`. Then check whether the `parse` method returns `null` (this would indicate an invalid date). See API doc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-

Answer (score 0):

neetha.

Your code is incorrect. The validation must be like this:

```
if (h >= 0 && h <= 23 && m >= 0 && m <= 59 && ss >= 0 && ss <= 59) {
    System.out.println("Valid test case" + h + ":" + m + ":" + ss);
}
```

Anyway, it would be better to use a class like `LocalTime` (if you use Java 8) in order to manage times:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(h, m, ss);
```

If the time is invalid, this code throws a `java.time.DateTimeException`.